# Передача массива в качестве аргумента при вызове метода через рефлексию(C#)

Tags: c#, массивы, рефлексия

Есть такой код

```
public static void Parser(string line)
    {
        string command = line.Split(' ')[0];
        string[] args = line.Split(' ').Skip(1).ToArray();
        Commands mc = new Commands();
        MethodInfo m = mc.GetType().GetMethod(command);
        object[] param = args.ToArray<object>();
        m.Invoke(mc, param);
    }
```

Необходимо передать массив args в следующий метод:

```
 class Commands
{
    public void write(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
    }
}
```

Собственно вопрос, как это сделать? Данный код не работает, исключение

> System.ArgumentException: "Невозможно преобразовать объект типа "System.String" к типу "System.String[]"."

Comment: Обычно в рефлексии передают так  `object[] param =  { param1, param2}` в вашем случае так  `object[] param =  {  args }` Откройте любой пример рефлексии.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло